# Operations on multiple slices of columns in Pandas DF basing on row values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

I am working with some very huge arrays of data that I have organized in a Pandas DataFrame. An example of what I have is more or less like this

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'vp':aux_vp,'vs':aux_vs,'den':aux_den,'layer':facies_vol})
         vp           layer
0        5163.788741  0.0
1        5062.234019  0.0
2        4869.894684  0.0
3        9126.546268  1.0
4        5566.053159  1.0
             ...      ...
1254523  6177.467626  0.0
1254524  4756.891403  0.0
1254525  6244.816685  2.0
```

Now, what I need is to calculate the average of the values in columns "vp", in slices defined by the values of "layer", so that the expected output would be

```
         vp    layer  averages
0        5163  0.0    5031.3
1        5062  0.0    5031.3
2        4869  0.0    5031.3
3        9126  1.0    7346
4        5566  1.0    7346
         ...   ...    ...
1254523  6177  0.0    5466.5
1254524  4756  0.0    5466.5
1254525  6244  2.0    6244
```

The repetition of the average value in each slice is a *bonus*. What I really cannot do is to do this operation without parsing through all the rows. I have already tried to do this using numpy, identifing the indexes where the the "layer" array changes and then calculating it with a for loop:

```
   vp= np.array(...) #same as vp in pandas column
    layer= np.array(...) #same as layer in pandas column
    averages= np.zeros((len(vp))

    indexes= np.add(np.where(layer[:-1] != layer[1:])[0],1) #here I compare the adjacent values of layer and store the index where they are different
    
    for i in range(1,len(indexes)):
        mean= np.mean(vp[indexes[i-1]:indexes[i]])
        averages[indexes[i-1]:indexes[i]]=mean
```

but it takes an eternity, considering the volume of data I have.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use `groupby` and `transform('mean')` after you create a key column to group on using `shift` and `cumsum`

```
df['averages'] = df.assign(key=(df['layer'] != df['layer'].shift()).cumsum()).groupby('key')['vp'].transform('mean')

                  vp  layer     averages
0        5163.788741    0.0  5031.972481
1        5062.234019    0.0  5031.972481
2        4869.894684    0.0  5031.972481
3        9126.546268    1.0  7346.299714
4        5566.053159    1.0  7346.299714
1254523  6177.467626    0.0  5467.179514
1254524  4756.891403    0.0  5467.179514
1254525  6244.816685    2.0  6244.816685
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group to get the means then merge the tables.

```
mean = df.groupby(by='layer').agg({'value': 'mean'}).rename(columns={'value': 'mean'}).reset_index()
df.merge(mean, on='layer')

value  layer         mean
0    4998.663295    0.0  5000.727034
1    4999.460336    0.0  5000.727034
2    5002.241608    0.0  5000.727034
3    5000.057680    0.0  5000.727034
4    5000.036647    0.0  5000.727034
5    4999.525570    0.0  5000.727034
6    5002.602431    0.0  5000.727034
7    5000.774510    0.0  5000.727034
8    5001.872130    0.0  5000.727034
9    5002.036133    0.0  5000.727034
10   9999.825662    1.0  9999.648100
11   9999.707490    1.0  9999.648100
12   9999.601844    1.0  9999.648100
13   9999.137278    1.0  9999.648100
14   9999.544681    1.0  9999.648100
15   9999.971940    1.0  9999.648100
16  10001.009895    1.0  9999.648100
17   9999.212977    1.0  9999.648100
18  10001.271304    1.0  9999.648100
19   9997.197929    1.0  9999.648100
```